How to I build a library (MQTT-C) using a prebuilt library (MbedTLS) as a dependency, while ensuring the include directories are actually included?
MbedTLS/CMake has been driving me crazy. Hopefully someone here can enlighten me over what I'm doing wrong.
I've been able to build MbedTLS, but when I try to use it as a dependency for MQTT-C, it doesn't seem to recognize a lot of the definitions that were used in MbedTLS. (By the way, I've tried this with a few other libraries that consume MbedTLS, and I get the same issues -- just using MQTT-C because it's the simplest example.)
Essentially, I defined variables in the file mbedtls_config.h which were used when building MbedTLS, but when I build MQTT-C using the prebuilt MbedTLS as a dependency, suddenly those definitions don't seem to be recognized.
I wrote this script for
#!/bin/bash

# Set the base directory
BASE_DIR=/home/pi/my-project

# Clone the mbedtls repository
if [ ! -d "mbedtls" ]; then
    git clone https://github.com/Mbed-TLS/mbedtls.git
    cd mbedtls
    git submodule update --init
    cd ..
fi

# Install the required Python packages
pip install -r mbedtls/scripts/basic.requirements.txt

# Create and navigate to the build directory
mkdir -p mbedtls/build
cd mbedtls/build

# Run cmake for native build
cmake \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$BASE_DIR \
    -DENABLE_PROGRAMS=OFF \
    -DENABLE_TESTING=OFF \
    -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-latomic" \
    -DUSE_SHARED_MBEDTLS_LIBRARY=Off \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
    ..

# Step 6: Build the project
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install

This works perfectly fine and builds properly. Then I run this script for building MQTT-C:
#!/bin/bash

# Define the directory where the MQTT-C repository will be cloned
export BASE_DIR=/home/pi/treat-dispenser-firmware

# Define the paths to MbedTLS include and lib directories
export MBEDTLS_INCLUDE_DIR=$BASE_DIR/include:$BASE_DIR/include/mbedtls:$BASE_DIR/include/everest:$BASE_DIR/include/psa
export MBEDTLS_LIB_DIR=$BASE_DIR/lib
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$BASE_DIR/lib/pkgconfig

# Clone the MQTT-C repository if it doesn't exist
if [ ! -d "$REPO_DIR" ]; then
    echo "Cloning the MQTT-C repository..."
    git clone https://github.com/LiamBindle/MQTT-C.git
fi

# Navigate to the repository directory
cd MQTT-C

# Create a build directory
mkdir -p build
cd build

# Run CMake to configure the build system with MbedTLS support
echo "Configuring the build with CMake..."
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$BASE_DIR \
      -DMQTT_C_MbedTLS_SUPPORT=ON \
      -DMBEDTLS_INCLUDE_DIRS=$MBEDTLS_INCLUDE_DIR \
      -DMBEDTLS_LIBRARY=$MBEDTLS_LIB_DIR/libmbedtls.a \
      -DMBEDCRYPTO_LIBRARY=$MBEDTLS_LIB_DIR/libmbedcrypto.a \
      -DMBEDX509_LIBRARY=$MBEDTLS_LIB_DIR/libmbedx509.a \
      ..

# Build the project
make
sudo make install

And I get a variety of errors that all look like this:
/home/pi/my-project/build_scripts_raspberry_pi/MQTT-C/examples/templates/mbedtls_sockets.h: In function ‘open_nb_socket’:
/home/pi/my-project/build_scripts_raspberry_pi/MQTT-C/examples/templates/mbedtls_sockets.h:74:5: error: unknown type name ‘mbedtls_x509_crt’
   74 |     mbedtls_x509_crt *ca_crt = &ctx->ca_crt;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/my-project/build_scripts_raspberry_pi/MQTT-C/examples/templates/mbedtls_sockets.h:86:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mbedtls_x509_crt_init’; did you mean ‘mbedtls_net_init’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   86 |     mbedtls_x509_crt_init(ca_crt);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |     mbedtls_net_init

(Again, there are dozens of examples here, just focusing on one.) Now, when I look at the file mbedtls_socket.h, it includes the file mbedtls/ssl.h. When I go to that file, it defines the function mbedtls_x509_crt_init, but it's within an if statement #if defined(MBEDTLS_X509_CRT_PARSE_C).
Here's the thing: The variable MBEDTLS_X509_CRT_PARSE_C is defined in the file mbedtls_config.h, which is in the same include folder as all the other MbedTLS files that it's finding. So it should know that MBEDTLS_X509_CRT_PARSE_C is defined and thus this function should be accessible.
However, this entire block of code starting after #if defined(MBEDTLS_X509_CRT_PARSE_C) is grayed out in VS Code, indicating that it doesn't think the MBEDTLS_X509_CRT_PARSE_C variable is defined. That's also what I think is happening when I build MQTT-C -- it doesn't think these variables are defined, for some reason.
Note that CMake does seem to be finding the include and lib folders for the prebuilt MbedTLS because it is finding ssl.h, even though somehow it is I guess not finding mbedtls_config.h which is in the exact same directory.
I've also tried adding in the -lmbedtls -lmbedx509 -lmbedcrypto flags, but that doesn't seem to help.
I've also tried doing the same thing with OpenSSL instead of MbedTLS, and I run into a very similar issue. I get this error:
/home/pi/my-project/MQTT-C/include/mqtt_pal.h:100:22: fatal error: openssl/bio.h: No such file or directory
  100 |             #include <openssl/bio.h>
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

When I'm absolutely sure that the folder that has this file in it has been included, so I don't know why it's not finding it.

use make VERBOSE=1 to see exactly what your compile statements are. i bet that will prove enlightening

also, in each of your bash scripts, compare BASE_DIR. in this first you define it as BASE_DIR=/home/pi/my-project and this is where you install MbedTLS. in the second you define it as BASE_DIR=/home/pi/treat-dispenser-firmware, and then define the locations of MBEDTLS_INCLUDE_DIR and MBEDTLS_LIB_DIR based on that. This is not where you installed MbedTLS, so naturally you'll have issues with missing include files.
